# Jenkins editable email notification attachment : Not attached in the mail

Tags: jenkins

As a post build action, have chosen editable email notification option and specified the file path something like **/XXX/index.html. 
I guess, the job is able to access the file but I don't receive the attachment in the mail.

Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending email to: XXXXX
Finished: FAILURE

Can anyone help me to get the attachment along with the mail?

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following, add a build step execute shell.

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/your-job-name/builds/$BUILD_NUMBER/ && 
cp changelog.xml /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/your-job-name/ && 
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/your-job-name/ && 
mv changelog.xml "build-${BUILD_NUMBER}-changelog.xml"
```

This then copies and renames the change log for the last build in to the workspace, all you need to do then is under attachments within Editable email notification put `build-$BUILD_NUMBER-changelog.xml`.

I then run a delete workspace when build is done with an exclude keeping anything important and getting rid of the change logs after they have been sent.

Answer (score 0):

The base directory for attachments is the Workspace of the job. Make sure the path you are giving in the Attachments field is relative to the jobs workspace which is $WORKSPACE env variable.

Comment: Thanks.. Yes, the path given is relative to the workspace. When I provided it wrong, I got "Cannot access file" like error message. After changed it, there are no error messages but still no attachment in the mail.

Comment: can you share the path to the file you are trying to attach along with the console log after the job completes. This will help understand what is happening in your job

Comment: Path of the File to be attached:///C:/Jenkins/workspace/pd-smoke-tests/productmodel/build/reports/tests/index.html

Comment: So from the absolute path you have given above - Workspace == C:/Jenkins/workspace/pd-smoke-tests and so in the Attachment field you should give something like /productmodel/build/reports/tests/index.html .. this will get picked up for sure

Comment: I tried with different ways also, still no attachment:                                             /productmodel/build/reports/tests/index.html                **/productmodel/build/reports/tests/index.html    $WORKSPACE/productmodel/build/reports/tests/index.html

Comment: Configured fresh new job and **/productmodel/build/reports/tests/index.html options works. Thanks very much Raghav..